# How to return keyboard control back to an QT window when clicked on it

Tags: c++, qt

I am having this weird bug.

I have a class that inherits both QObject and QGraphicsRectItem.

I am having it do something if a key like space bar is pressed. However if I click outside a window, like say my desktop for example, the key no longer works. I tried clicking on the QT window to make the key responsive again but no luck.
Here is my code

Header:

```
    class rectangle : public QObject,  public QGraphicsRectItem{
    public: 
    rectangle();
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
    }
```

cpp file:

```
rectangle::rectangle(){}

void rectangle::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event){
if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Space){
// do something
qDebug() << "Key pressed";
   }
}
```

Normally, clicking on a program would give it back the input control but it isn't the case here. What do I need to do to make the keyPressedEvent worked again after I clicked on another application or just an empty area of my desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `keyPressEvent` does only work if `QGraphicsRectItem` has focus. This means, if you switch back to your Qt application the focus of `QGraphicsRectItem` may get lost and another widget (i. e QLabel, MainWindow, etc.) will have focus. Then the `keyPressEvent` of `QGraphicsRectItem` will not trigger. You can use `installEventFilter` to install your `keyPressEvent` filter on multiple widgets, or you simply use an application wide shortcut.

```
QShortcut *shortcut = new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Space), this);
connect(shortcut, &QShortcut::activated, [](){ qDebug() << "Space pressed"; });
```