# qt eventfilter keypress does nothing

Tags: qt, animation, keypress, eventfilter

I started working with QT and want to program a little game named Pong ( 2 player and a ball). The left player should be moved with the keys 'W' and 'S', the right player with the arrow keys up and down. I have a class Game to handle my animation. There I have an eventfilter to handle the keyPress

```
bool Game::eventFilter(QObject *target, QEvent *e)
{
    Q_UNUSED(target);

    bool handled = false;
    if(e->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        QKeyEvent *keyEvent = (QKeyEvent *)e;

        if(keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_W)
        {
            leftPlayerDir = ((leftPlayerDir == 0) ? 5 : leftPlayerDir);
            handled = true;
        }
        else if(keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_S)
        {
            leftPlayerDir  = ((leftPlayerDir == 0) ? -5 : leftPlayerDir);
            handled = true;
        }
        else if(keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Up)
        {
            rightPlayerDir  = ((rightPlayerDir == 0) ? 5 : rightPlayerDir);
            handled = true;
        }
        else if(keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Down)
        {
            rightPlayerDir  = ((rightPlayerDir == 0) ? -5 : rightPlayerDir);
            handled = true;
        }
    }
     return handled;
}
```

and in my class Pong, where I set up the Mainwindow and handle the buttons, I have a line to install the eventfilter

```
ui->animation->installEventFilter(game);
```

If I start my program the animation is working, but the players are not moving on keyPress and I don't know why. Some ideas?

Comment: The eventFilter is only triggered when your widget has focus. Since it's not triggered it does not have focus. You may want to install the eventFilter on the widget that has focus as well.

Comment: Ja, das stimmt, aber wenn ich ein Spiel starte, rufe ich an `ui->animation->setFocus()` to set the Focus on my QGraphicsView and then the eventFilter should work but it doesn't

Comment: Can I install the eventFilter somewhere to get always the keyEvent? independent from the focus and widget?

Comment: You can create an application wide shortcuts. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49806724/3606329 - `setFocus` can get lost quickly, it's better to figure out which widget has focus when you press your keys and then install the eventFilter on it.